# Conexión a BBDD con VB.NET sin instalar nada

Tags: vb.net, base-de-datos, .net

Me gustaría saber si con VB .NET (o C#) es posible acceder a bases de datos sin tener que instalar nada. Es decir, Java (por ejemplo) copia un fichero .jar y con él accede a la base de datos correspondiente, pero no instala nada.

¿Es posible esto con .NET?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿A que base de datos?

Comment: la respuesta es, todo depende de a que base de datos. no hay una respuesta correcta para esto, a menos que especifiques una base de datos en particular y una forma de conectarse en particular.

Answer (score 0):

Si en tu proyecto de .net , pones agregar elemento nuevo  , Vas a la parte de DATA , ahi tienes opciones para conectarte a bases de datos SQL , tienes muchas , yo particularmente , uso CODE FIRST TO DATABASE , significa que apartir de tu base de datos te crea el modelo de datos , y ya con eso puedes insertar , nmodificar , borrar de tu base de datos muy facil con 3 lineas de codigo , te dejo aca unos links de interes , si te sirve mi respuesta por favor marcala como correcta

link de interes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx

aca tenes lo mismo pero en video https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/ef/code-first-to-existing-database-ef6-1-onwards-